# What is the default Ubuntu launcher called and how is it configured?

Tags: launcher, .desktop

I'm not after suggestions to use tweaks or alacarte.

I'm running 18.04 but about to install 22.XX.  Where are the .desktop files for the default launcher,  how should they be manually edited and how are they added and removed dynamically?

Cheers,
bitrat

Comment: @user535733  ... I mean, what is the underlying process that adds and removes items?  And how can I replicate it's actions manually and/or examine and modify the entries?

Comment: ...also, drag what in?  From where?